# Filter Multiple Values using ngx-filter-pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to filter an array using [ngx-filter-pipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filter-pipe). I have successfully filtered if has a single value condition. I don't know how to filter any value in a array. Please help me out.

**Angular**

```
<input type="text" id="search"  class="form-control" name="search" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.name"> 
<tr *ngFor="let data of datas | filterBy: userFilter">
  <td>{{data.name}}</td>
  <td>{{data.age}}</td>
  <td>{{data.country}}</td>
</tr>
```

**TS**

```
userFilter: any = { name: '' };
```

**Data**

```
datas:[
  { name:"abc", age:17, country:"US" },
  { name:"xyz", age:25, country:"India" }
]
```

How should I handle my `ngModel` If put muliple parameters in `userFilter`

Stackblitz: [Similar Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-filter-pipe?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: you're correctly using the attribute as *data*, not *datas*, I hope.

Comment: Edited. Check again

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your filter.

The package expects the filter to be as below:

```
const filter = {
  name: {
    $or: ['abc']
  },
  age: {
    $or: ['17']
  }
  ...
};
```

As per the [documentations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filter-pipe)

```
$or expects an Array.
```

Comment: I need to search age and country too

Comment: If answer satisfy your first question, please accept it. I can help with the other query in other question.

Comment: `I don't know how to filter any value in a array` I added this in my question

Comment: Updated the answered. Hope this helps.

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="userFilter.name"` how should I modifiy this. This is my issue

Comment: For other attribute you need to get an other input or need to handle it dynamic if you prefer to have a single input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208693/discussion-between-varit-j-patel-and-chris).